# ContentCachingRequestWrapper produces empty output when used in filter, but not when used in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am puzzled by the following issue. Consider this simple servlet filter:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ContentCachingFilter implements Filter {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        var wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
        var requestBody = new String(wrappedRequest.getContentAsByteArray());
        log.debug("RequestBody: " + requestBody);

        var wrappedResponse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
        var responseBody = new String(wrappedResponse.getContentAsByteArray());
        log.debug("ResponseBody: " + responseBody);

        chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, wrappedResponse);
    }
}
```

... and a simple controller

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class LoggingController {
    // ...

    @PostMapping(value = "/")
    public String doGreet(@RequestBody String name, HttpServletRequest request) {
        var requestWrapper = (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) request;
        var body = new String(requestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray());

        return "Moin " + body;
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain why my controller is able to read the request body but the filter isn't?

Comment: The `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` will only cache the request after it has been read. In the filter you aren't reading it but directly getting the content (which is not read and thus empty at that point). In the controller it has been read due to the `@RequestBody` and hence the cached content it filled.